# Android: Understanding using one IntentService with multiple actions

Tags: android, intentservice

I have a problem with intent not getting delivered to an `IntentService` under a specific activity flow: This is the scenario:

1. Consider 3 activities, Home, B and C. C has 2 fragments CF1 and CF2.
2. B, CF1 and CF2 use the same IntentService class but with different actions.
3. IntentService gets started using `startService(Intent)`. (getActivity().startService(Intent) for Fragments)
4. Wherever IntentService gets started, I make sure it gets stopped using `stopService(intent)` if it is running in Activity/Fragment's `onStop()`.
5. If the activity flow is Home -> C - > CF1 - >CF2, everything works.
6. If the activity flow is Home -> B - > C -> CF1 - > CF2, then `onHandleIntent` is never invoked after startService(Intent) from CF2. B and CF1 intents are handled. For debugging, I tried by waiting for IntentService to complete in Activity B and then go to CF1 -> CF2, still the same problem. CF1 never seems to have any problems in starting the same intent service. When I tried creating a new `IntentService` class for CF2, it worked.

My understanding was that IntentService has a queue for intents. If the service is running for first time , onStartCommand is invoked (which we are not supposed to handle for IntentService). If the service is already running, onHandleIntent is invoked for every subsequent call of startService.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong but not clear as what. I have tried looking into other stackoverflow questions but didn't help. The code I am using is pretty straightforward:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".service.ExampleIntentService" />
```

**Activity B**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       .......
       intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExampleIntentService.class);
       intent.setAction(StringConstants.ACTION_B);
       serviceRunning = true; //set to false in onReceiveResult 
       startService(intent);
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
      if(serviceRunning && intent != null)
          stopService(intent)
}
```

**Fragment CF1**

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(StringConstants.ACTION_CF1);
    serviceRunning = true; //set to false in onReceiveResult 
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
      if(serviceRunning && intent != null)
          stopService(intent)
}
```

The code is exactly the same for fragment, CF2

Comment: An IntentService does not queue intents.  startService is called for every inbound intent; all of the calls are queued on a Looper thread local to the service.  While stopping the service when it is not doing anything, is good practice, it is only an optimization.  I suggest you quit doing it until your app is working properly

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike I dont understand the difference between 'does not queue intents' and 'calls are queued on a Looper thread local to the service'. I will try calling stopService and see. But would it be better just to create a separate intentService? I know that will work. edit: Also I am not sure why am I not seeing the same problem with fragment CF1.

Comment: The difference is that the intents are *always* delivered to IntentService.startService.  The startService method enqueues the calls on a local queue from which they are dequeued by another thread, and delivered as calls to onHandleIntent.  All of them.  See Mark's answer below: stop calling stopService.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding was... If the service is running for first time , onStartCommand is invoked (which we are not supposed to handle for IntentService). If the service is already running, onHandleIntent is invoked for every subsequent call of startService.

No. `onStartCommand()` is called for every `startService()` call. `onHandleIntent()` is called for every `startService()` call made to an `IntentService`, unless you do something in `onStartCommand()` to change normal behavior.

> IntentService gets started using startService(Intent).

You send commands to an `IntentService` using `startService()`.

> Wherever IntentService gets started, I make sure it gets stopped using stopService(intent)

That is an exceptionally bad idea. `IntentService` will stop itself when all `startService()` calls have been processed, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate.

Comment: Like @G.BlakeMeike and you said, I tried removing stopService and it worked. But again I am not sure what the right approach is when the user moves away from an activity which has a IntentService is running. You say it is a bad idea, shouldn't we just stop the service if the user is moving away from the activity?

Comment: @Prasanna: The point behind using an `IntentService` is because you *want* the work to continue "if the user is moving away from the activity". If you didn't want that, don't use an `IntentService` -- just use a thread.